# Java final variable in a function

Tags: java, variables, final

I always thought that final variables are only assigned once.
Can someone please enlighten me on what the final keyword does in this case?
Does it mean that it is only "final" until the function returns?

```
public void onClick(View view) {
    final int x = new Random().nextInt();
    System.out.println(x);
}
```

Output:

```
03-01 14:18:25.022: I/System.out(26253): 416604980
03-01 14:18:25.332: I/System.out(26253): -1080822415
03-01 14:18:25.522: I/System.out(26253): -170506517
03-01 14:18:26.982: I/System.out(26253): 1438898132
03-01 14:18:27.112: I/System.out(26253): 401245673
```

Comment: The scope of `x` between the `{` to `}` which it is in.  When you exit the method, it doesn't exist.

Comment: Possibly duplicate of [Quesion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7924452/final-variables-inside-a-method-in-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`x`, as a `final` local variable, can be assigned only once within the scope of its existence, which is the body of the `onClick` method.

Each call to that method creates a new `x` variable that can only be assigned once.

Answer (score 1):

This is a local variable, it's not just only `final` until the method ends, it only exists until the method ends.

At the closing }, the variable becomes eligible for garbage collectioning.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in this case `x` is an int that as soon it get an initial random value, the variable can not be changed anymore...

Answer (score 1):

It means it can only be assigned once during its lifetime, and the lifetime of local variables spans the method they're in.

Answer (score 0):

There are 5 invokations or callings in each call x variable is defined and assigned. Variable x is local, it is in scope on onClick method.